# Predicting values in ordinal regression analysis with R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I have two questions that are almost completely related to how to do things in R.

I am running an ordinal regression analysis in R. The dependent variable has three levels (0=no action; 1=warning; 2=sanction).

I use the `lrm` command in  the `rms` package:

```
print( res1<- lrm(Y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6, y=TRUE, x=TRUE, data=mydata))
```

I simply couldn't make any sense of the information generated my `?predict.lrm`. What I want to do is to calculate the marginal effects of all explanatory variables for each level of the dependent variable. In Stata, this is very simple: mfx compute, predict (outcome(#0)); mfx compute, predict (outcome(#2)) and mfx compute, predict (outcome(#3)).

So my **first question** is: how do I  generate marginal effects for each outcome in R? Please keep in mind that my skills in R are not advanced.

The second question is related to interaction effects, which I need to include in the same model:

```
print( res1<- lrm(Y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x5*x6, y=TRUE, x=TRUE, data=mydata))
```

If I knew the answer to the first question, I would have ran marginal effects with the interaction term included. Then, I would have plotted the predicted values of the interaction term.

So the **second question** is: how do I plot the effects (predicted values) of variables in the interaction term?

Many thanks!

EDIT: 
Small sample from my dataset (only one country)

```
dput(mydatasample)

structure(list(year = 1989:2014, country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Canada", class = "factor"), 
    id = structure(1:26, .Label = c("CAN 1989", "CAN 1990", "CAN 1991", 
    "CAN 1992", "CAN 1993", "CAN 1994", "CAN 1995", "CAN 1996", 
    "CAN 1997", "CAN 1998", "CAN 1999", "CAN 2000", "CAN 2001", 
    "CAN 2002", "CAN 2003", "CAN 2004", "CAN 2005", "CAN 2006", 
    "CAN 2007", "CAN 2008", "CAN 2009", "CAN 2010", "CAN 2011", 
    "CAN 2012", "CAN 2013", "CAN 2014"), class = "factor"), stage1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x2 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), x3 = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), x4 = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
    31L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 
    29L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 25L, 24L, 23L, NA, NA, NA), x5 = structure(1:26, .Label = c("17,12528685", 
    "17,14022279", "17,15382785", "17,16610202", "17,17704534", 
    "17,18665779", "17,19493938", "17,20571103", "17,21628118", 
    "17,22493732", "17,23321101", "17,242041", "17,25213621", 
    "17,26110753", "17,27106985", "17,2810902", "17,29094924", 
    "17,29891768", "17,30861622", "17,31943819", "17,33088659", 
    "17,34202619", "17,35190237", "17,36381421", "17,37537139", 
    "17,38618117"), class = "factor"), x5.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("year", "country", 
"id", "stage1", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x5.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide a data sample. Paste the output of `dput(mydata)` into your question. If your data frame is large, then just paste a small sample of the data frame.

Comment: @eipi10 sorry for the delayed response! I pasted a small sample from my dataset. Really appreciate if you could help me with this.

Comment: @eipi10  and please let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @eipi10 very sorry for being pushy.., but do you think you can help me with this?